# Как отметить метод на который уже написан unit тест

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Тесты пишутся уже на готовый функционал, скажите есть ли какое то правило отметки метода что на него уже написан тест ? Может быть какой то специальный тег phpdoc.

Проект на Php.

Comment: Можете просто вписать в свой coding gaid специальное допущение что методы покрытые unit тестами должны иметь в php-doc блок `@unittest` или `@testuproved` или же писать todo на каждый не покрытый метод `//todo this method need unittest` и любая ide будет подсвечивать данные todo после покрытия todo можно удалить, и остануться все todo около не покрытых тестами методав.

Comment: TDD предписывает _сначала_ писать тесты, а уже _потом_ реальные методы. Таким образом, вы вообще не сможете попасть в ситуацию, когда на метод нет теста. Если же вы не фанатичный адепт TDD, то вам стоит контролировать степень покрытия кода тестами: при падении ниже некоторой заранее известно величины бросать написание нового кода и плотно браться за тесты.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри PHPUnit Code Coverage Analysis

Может это поможет:

[phpunit на русском](http://itfor.xyz/tag/phpunit/)